# How to connect server to google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, server

I know that it is possible to connect chrome extension with a server, but is it possible to connect the server with chrome extension? I need to push some data to chrome extension from server and than push it back to server. Is it possible? And if yes, how?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Open a WebSocket connection in your extension.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer